# Next JS Axios: fetch API data with key for CoinMarketCap

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, axios, coinmarketcap

No big experience with NextJS/React. I've been readings posts about this topic, but nothing seems to work for me.I am trying to learn how curl request work using Axios in Nextjs. so I am trying to  to fetch data from an Coinmarketcap API using Axios and it requires a key. I don't know how to pass it through axios. I tested the curl request and it worked. but the axios request doesn't work.

This is the curl request
`curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: api-key-here" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD" -G https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest`

and this is my code IN nextJS

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("running effect");
   axios
     .get(
       "https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",
       {
         params: {
           start: "1",
           limit: "5000",
           convert: "USD",
         },
         headers: {
           "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "api-key-here",
           Accept: "application/json",
         },
       }
     )
     .then((res) => {
       console.log(res);
     });
 }, []);
```

the errors I get

````
 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

       GET https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD net::ERR_FAILED```
````

Comment: Please include the call response from the dev tab

Comment: I just added the response

Comment: Its given in the [docs](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Introduction) the api calls from javascrip client is prohibited, to protect the api key, so you need to make the call from your backend api server

Comment: @YannHervee I'd recommend checking out the MDN page on CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. This is a security feature implemented by web browsers that prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page.

Comment: @Azzy right. Thanks I didn't see that.

Comment: @YannHervee, welcome hope you are able to sort it out